# Selenium python - AttributeError

Tags: python, selenium

```
def page():
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        pages = driver.find_element_by_id('searchResults_links')
        time.sleep(2)
        print(pages, 'pg')
        print(pages.text, "pg_t")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Ошибка получения кол-ва страниц.')
        driver.refresh()
        page()
    else:
        print('Вернул')
        return pages
print(page().text)
```

Пытаюсь спарсить количество страниц. Библиотеки устнановлены, функции вызваны.
Если ошибок нет, то код работает. Если ошибка с загрузкой страницы есть, то по идее страница должна перезагрузиться и функция должна выполняться заново, пока ошибка не будет устранена.
**Ниже напишу, что происходит при ошибке:**

1. функция выполняется второй раз, исполняется `pages = driver.find_element_by_id('searchResults_links')`
2. `print(pages, 'pg')` выдаёт селениум код
3. `print(pages.text, "pg_t")` выдаёт номер страницы. Проблем вроде нету
4. Возвращается pages
5. Должно распечатать pages.text `print(page().text)`. НО выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. Хотя в фунции всё выдавало без ошибок. В чём проблема?

Comment: Когда случается ошибка, ваша функция ничего не возвращает (в блоке except отсутствует return)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Answer (score 0):

1 Если вы хотите получить количество страниц, то надо использовать не

```
pages = driver.find_element_by_id('searchResults_links'), а
pages = driver.find_elements_by_id('searchResults_links')
```

и потом брать их `len`
2 Чтоб высести их количество потом надо сделать

```
print(len(pages))
```

3 Если такой локатор как я понял не один (поэтому и find_element**s**), то текст надо брать у каждого локатора в цикле.
К примеру, чтоб достать текст первого локатора, используйте:

```
expected_text = pages[0].text
```

а цикл:

```
for el in pages:
    print(el.text)
```

Comment: Объект pages один. Мне нужно было узнать лишь почему выдаёт ошибку. Комментарий под вопросом помог. Была ошибка в фунции. Но и вам спасибо за ответ)